# Can you use a powershell script to create a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

So this may be an odd request and maybe I'm going about this all wrong but I also have a unique situation. I have servers that are sometimes cloned and I need to run a script that I created on the clones servers. Due to the nature of the clones they cannot be connected to a network.

Currently I am manually putting the generic script on each server before cloning and then running the script on the clone server.

What I would like to do is have a script that runs and gathers all the information, say installed programs as an example, and generate a custom version of my current script on the servers before they are cloned.

I have both the powershell script that gets the server information and the generic one that makes the changes to the clone but I have not found a way to merge the two or any documentation so I don't know if i am hitting a limitation with this one.

Edit for more explanation and examples. I'm doing this from my phone atm so I dont have an example I can post.

Current I have a script that has a set number of applications to uninstall, registry keys to remove, services to stop ect. In another application I have a list of all the software that we have for each server and I can pull that data for each server. What I need to do is pull the data for each server, and have a script placed on each server that will uninstall just the programs for that server.

Currently the script has to run through every potential software and try to uninstall it and then check the other application to see if there are any additional programs that need to be uninstalled.

Hope this extra info helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stop thinking of it as code.

Use script 1 to export blocks of text into a new file.  for example, you might have a configuration that says all Dell servers must have this line of code run:

```
Set-DELL -attribute1 unmanaged
```

where on HP, the script would have been

```
Set-HP -attribute1 unmanaged
```

on web servers, you want:

```
set-web -active yes
```

where if not a web server, you want nothing..  so, your parent script code would look like:

```
$Dell = "Set-DELL -attribute1 unmanaged"
$HP = "Set-HP -attribute1 unmanaged"
$web = "set-web -active yes"

if (Get-servermake -eq "Dell")
{
    $dell | out-file Child.ps1 -append
}

if (Get-servermake -eq "HP")
{
    $HP | out-file Child.ps1 -append
}

if (Get-webserver -eq $true)
{
    $web | out-file Child.ps1 -append
}
```

The result is a customized script for the specific server, child.ps1.

Now, you can take this and run with it.  You could say add functionality to the child script like "Is it an AD controller", etc.

However, you might be better off having all of this in a single script, and just block off sections that don't apply in an if statement for example.

I'm still not totally sure I understand what your asking.  If I've missed the mark, tell me how, and I'll tell you how to tweak this better.  (And hopefully obvious is that the Get-whatever is sample code.  I don't expect that to be what your using to determine a computer make/model/etc)